# Syntax Error when running amplify init --appId XXX

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm writing a React Webapp using the amplify console. While installing the cli, I followed the steps under "Setup your Backend Environment" which involves:

```
$ npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli

$ amplify init --appId IDNUMBER
```

But the second command throws this error message:

```
Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeValue (/usr/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/lib/input-params-manager.js:31:32)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/lib/input-params-manager.js:6:31
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeInputParams (/usr/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/lib/input-params-manager.js:4:45)
    at constructExeInfo (/usr/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/commands/init.js:72:22)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/commands/init.js:52:21
    at step (/usr/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/commands/init.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (/usr/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/commands/init.js:14:53)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/lib/commands/init.js:8:71
```

I can't identify what JSON file it's trying to read.